# Build LaTeX Document with Azure DevOps CD/CI

Tags: latex, azure, pdflatex

We are asked at school to submit good quality reports, so as a team, we have decided to use LaTeX instead of MS Word. We use Git to share the code across the team members. Our hosting service for version control is Azure DevOps.

Now we want to use the CI capabilities of DevOps for building our PDF. And it fails. In the past, we have used GitLab for that purpose with the following yaml file:

```
compile_pdf:
image: aergus/latex
script:
  - latexmk -pdf main.tex
artifacts:
  paths:
    - main.pdf
```

Today, this exact file generates the following error with DevOps:

```
azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 1, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'compile_pdf'
```

Has anyone used DevOps before for compiling with LaTeX?

Comment: You'll have to update the syntax of the file. You can find the schema here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema

Comment: Any luck updating the syntax? If not I'll give it a try and post an answer...

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1453924/999889