# How to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline with texlive?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure, latex, pdflatex

I have a repo with LaTeX `.tex` files. In every commit I would like a pipeline to create PDF with them.

I have created a pipeline with the `pdflatex main.tex` command.

However, `texlive` is not installed in the vm. So I get the error:

`/home/.../f170215a.sh: line 2: pdflatex: command not found`

How to go around that? Are there options of cloud based VMs in Azure with texlive installed? Or do I have to create my own VM for that?

The pipeline yaml is as follows:

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- bash: | 
    echo Starting pdflatex
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
    echo Done pdflatex.
```

Answer (score 0):

First part solved by installing the requirements in the pipeline script:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

The yml pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- bash: | 
    sudo apt-get install texlive     
    echo Starting pdflatex
    pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
    echo Done pdflatex.
```

Now I just need to retrieve the pdf file. But that's another topic =)