# Azure DevOps Pipeline: compile and retrieve LaTex pdf

Tags: latex, azure-devops

I believe the compiling part is working, using this.:
[How to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline with texlive?](https://superuser.com/questions/1453918/how-to-set-up-an-azure-devops-pipeline-with-texlive)

changed only the main.tex since my file has a different name. Build succeeds.

How to retrieve the file?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to publish, make it available for download, and push to repository:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops/latex-tex-pipeline/m-p/3734301/highlight/false#M1248

The pdf is available in the successful run of the pipeline; and is now pushed to the repository.